# Python: Small for statement without list

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I'm trying to optimize my code. I'm trying to make my for-statement as short as possible. The problem is that the short for-statment is (ofcourse) "returning" a list. I want it to "return" a string.

```
b = [key2 for key2 in LUT_value.keys() if LUT_value[key2] == self.value]
```

Keys is a string, f.g it could be "Name". Problem is that `b` becomes:

```
b = ['Name']
```

And I'm returning `a + ' ' + b` which won't work. How could I work around this and still keep the small statement? If possible.

Comment: You mean you wanted to return the *first* such matching value?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: I don't think `a` matters; the OP is showing they are using string concatenation.

Comment: What exactly are you optimizing for?  (Regardless, you should drop the `keys()` and extra lookup cruft, just iterate over `items()`)

Comment: If key's is a list, then why not select the `b[0]` or the first match?

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: because the corresponding value wouldn't match `self.value`.

Comment: _..for-statement as short as possible._ - Why do you want to make it short, and is that related to optimization?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, the first matching value.

Comment: @roippi The look-up-table is used to convert a value to an actual name ( string ). "optimizing" is maybe the wrong name for it, i'm trying to achive as short code as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you needed to find the *first* such matching value, use the [`next()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions):

```
b = next((key2 for key2, value in LUT_value.items() if value == self.value), '')
```

This produces either your first `key2` value that matches the criteria, or an empty string if there is no such value. I used [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) rather than loop over `dict.keys()`, then look up individual values. In addition, looping over `dict.keys()` is redundant; just loop over the `dict` object directly if you want to iterate over just the keys.

I do wonder if you perhaps should store an *inverse* mapping instead:

```
inverse_LUT_values = {value: key for key, value in LUT_value.items()}
```

then just use:

```
b = inverse_LUT_values.get(self.value, '')
```

or even

```
b = inverse_LUT_values[self.value]
```

with `inverse_LUT_values` stored for re-use. It doesn't appear to matter to you if there are multiple keys with the same value that could match, so the inverse mapping just keeps one such key.

Comment: Okey, looks like a good soloution. Did not know about this function. Exactly i'm trying to find the first matching one ( There will only be one). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `next` with a generator expression:

```
b = next(key2 for key2 in LUT_value.keys() if LUT_value[key2] == self.value)
```

Note, this will raise a `StopIteration` if the value doesn't exist.  If the value isn't guaranteed to exist, you'll either need to catch the error and do something with it (or let it propogate I suppose...) or you can supply a default to next:

```
value_gen = (key2 for key2 in LUT_value.keys() if LUT_value[key2] == self.value)
some_default = 'Default Yeah!'
b = next(value_gen, some_default)
```

Comment: Note, there is likely no advantage to `LUT_value.keys()` -- iterating over a dict already iterates over the keys... `(key2 for key2 in LUT_value if ...)`

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Fair enough.  Op was acting like it was a fore-gone conclusion that the value would be in there ... Anyway, I've updated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question appropriately.  When you do

```
b = [key2 for key2 in LUT_value.keys() if LUT_value[key2] == self.value]
```

You have a list with one string?  If that's the case do:

```
b = [key2 for key2 in LUT_value.keys() if LUT_value[key2] == self.value][0]
```